Automatically installing required .NET Framework during app installation
I made a project in C# which now needs to be finished for deployment. I'm using the Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022 Extension to make an Installer for the project. The finished app consists of two projects: One VSTO app which runs perfectly fine upon installation, and a Winforms project which says that the .NET Desktop Runtime needs to be installed first. The VSTO Project uses the second project as a process at some point, and once this process starts, it just tells me to install the runtime.
I already checked the .NET Desktop Runtime 8.0.7 (x64) - the required one - in the prerequisites window of my setup project, which, to my understanding, is supposed to download the required components. I am not sure if I am missing something, but nothing gets installed.

What are you using for deployment? Clickonce, something else?

I already solved it, but thank you. The Extension creates two files: one .exe and one .msi. I always only used the .msi to install, but it turns out that the .exe is the one checking for the prerequisites and then calls the .msi afterwards. So after I ran the .exe instead of the .msi, it worked fine.
